# Cannot get text box value using Jquery on change event After click server side button event?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I get the textbox value using Jquery onchange event and i assigned the value to Hiddenfield like the following code..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtSearchZip").change(function () {               
                $("#hdfSearchZip").val($("#txtSearchZip").val());

                alert($("#hdfSearchZip").val());              
            });
        })
```

I get the proper value (Example: Alert returned value) Untill I click the server side button click event.After I click the server side button if i type the value to textbox that value not assigned to hiddenfield.

what i want is even before and after click the button (server side Button Click event),If i type any value in text box that value assigned to hiddenfield is there any way ?

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: If you click a server side button then likely it will post back your page. So next time the page loads, that is a fresh copy of the page. Maybe that's the issue. But you didn't really provide enough information or code for us to be sure what is really going on.

Answer (score 0):

on page refresh the documents get loaded again so if you are submitting form and then the page is getting refreshed then you can't hold that value in hidden field,if you want you can use browser localStorage to set item and get it back once the page reloads.the localStorage Object that too has certain limitations